# Filtering on Recent files query not working with ms graph java SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

What I am trying to do is filter out specific files(PDF) from the recent query of MS-SDK. I am using 'endsWith' filter to query out the files.
I am using:: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?filter=endswith(name, 'pdf').
This query is working fine for personal account, and I am getting 501-Not implemented error for business account.
Error message::

com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphFatalServiceException: Unexpected exception returned from the service.Error code: notSupported
Error message: Only createdDateTime is supported for filtering

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/microsoft.graph.recent?%24filter=endswith%28name%2C%20%27pdf%27%29&%24top=50
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.10.0
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


501 : Not Implemented
Cache-Control : no-cache
client-request-id : 7f4ad7bb-d10d-4787-8cde-fbc58b7398fa
Content-Type : application/json
Date : Mon, 12 Apr 2021 10:40:24 GMT
request-id : 2394348c-bbd5-4713-bf88-07655d343478
Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Vary : Accept-Encoding
x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South India","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"MA1PEPF00001509"}}
{
  "error": {
    "code": "notSupported",
    "message": "Only createdDateTime is supported for filtering",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-04-12T10:40:25",
      "request-id": "2394348c-bbd5-4713-bf88-07655d343478",
      "client-request-id": "7f4ad7bb-d10d-4787-8cde-fbc58b7398fa"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this known issue on MS-SDK side?

Comment: AFAIK, filter is not supported because there is no sign of Odata query parameters in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma  Though not mentioned in documentation, this API is working when I want to filter specific files for personal account, but error coming in case of Business account.

Comment: @Tushar yeah I see the same result. Sounds like filter is not enabled for business account, hence its not in the documentation either. If its not officially documented then it means its not supported or tested by them.

Comment: @Dev is there any other API you know of which could help me give only certain mimetype (in my case 'pdf') files using recents API ?

Comment: Unfortunately not that i am aware of or no other equivalent API exists.